# Exact vs approximate Riemann solvers

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, terminology, hyperbolic-equations

I am trying to understand numerical methods for conservation laws. I am confused with few terminologies.  I have the following doubts.

1. When do we say that a numerical scheme for a conservation law is a [Riemann solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_solver)?
2. What is the difference between approximate and exact Riemann solvers?
3. I read that Godunov scheme is an exact Riemann solver, but is there any other scheme which is exact Riemann solver?

Answer (score 0):

To make everything clear, let us go back to *Godunov's method* for scalar conservation laws $u_t + f(u)_x = 0$. Godunov's method reads
$$
u_i^{n+1} = u_i^n - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(f_{i+1/2} - f_{i-1/2})
$$
where $u_i^n \simeq u(x_i, t_n)$, $x_{i+1} = x_i+\Delta x$, $t_{n+1} = t_n+\Delta t$, and $f_{i+1/2}$ is the numerical flux at $x_{i+1/2}$. The latter is given by
$f_{i+1/2} = f (u^*)$,
where $u^*$ is obtained by evaluating the solution to the Riemann problem
$$
u(x,t_n) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& u_i^n & & \text{if}\quad x<x_{i+1/2}\\
& u_{i+1}^n & & \text{if}\quad x>x_{i+1/2}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
at $(x_{i+1/2}, t_{n+1})$ (see Sec. 4.11 of [1]). If this computation does not require all the Riemann solution, it requires a full knowledge of its structure, i.e. what we call an *exact Riemann solver*. This notion is intrinsically linked to the Godunov method.

In some cases it may be very expensive to evaluate $u^*$ exactly as defined above. Thus, *approximate Riemann solvers* are sometimes preferred. For instance, one can name the Roe, HLLE, and HLLC solvers (see Sec. 15.3 of [1]). Those methods introduce approximations of $u^*$ which are easier to compute than the exact $u^*$. However, one should be careful since approximate Riemann solvers can introduce artifacts for particular solutions (e.g. transsonic rarefactions and slow-moving shocks).

---

[1] R.J. LeVeque, Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems, Cambridge University Press, 2002, [doi:10.1017/CBO9780511791253](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Harry49's answer, I would recommend you a book to read if you want to know more about Riemann solvers from basic to advanced things:

**E.F. Toro, Riemann solvers and numerical methods for fluid dynamics, 3rd edition, 2009**

I know it helped me a lot.